# Ajax post request to .NET Core action and getting result not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I need to implement email sending modal popup and I'm almost done except ajax send request not hit to success or failure

When I click the send button (id:**end-email**) It successfully hit the .NET Core action and action return status correctly.

**But the problem is my ajax call not waiting for the result and automatically closing popup which is not required. I need to show the message instead of closing popup.**

```html
<div id="sendemail-window" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sendemail-window-title">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 50%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-weight:600;" id="sendemail-window-title">Shipment Request Email </h4>
            </div>
            <form  id="InStockPendingShipments" name="InStockPendingShipments">
                <input type="hidden" id="selectedPOIds" name="selectedPOIds" value="" />
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <nop-label asp-for="SendEmail.Subject" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <nop-editor asp-for="SendEmail.Subject" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="SendEmail.Subject"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <nop-label asp-for="SendEmail.Message" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <nop-textarea asp-for="SendEmail.Message" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="SendEmail.Message"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                &nbsp;
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <ul id="selected-po-list" class="selected-po-list">
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <div class="input-group input-group-short">
                            <label id="lblSaveResult" name="lblSaveResult" style="margin-top: 10px;font-weight: 500;"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                &nbsp;
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="send-email">
                                    Send Email
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                       $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('#send-email').click(function () { 
                                $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: '@Url.Action("SendInStockRequestEmail","InStockPendingShipments")',
                                       data: emailData(),
                                         success: function (msg) {
                                       
                                             alert("111 success");
                                        },
                                    error: function (req, status, error) {  
                                            alert(22225,error);
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .done(function () {
                                        alert("success");
                                    })
                                    .fail(function () {
                                        alert(44444,"error");
                                    });

                                 });

                        });


                          function emailData() {

                                        var data = {
                                            SelectedPOIds: $("#selectedPOIds").val(),
                                            Message: $('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.SendEmail.Message)').val(),
                                            Subject: $('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.SendEmail.Subject)').val()

                                        };

                                        addAntiForgeryToken(data);
                                        return data;
                                      }


                        $('#sendemail-window').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
                            $('#SendEmail_Message').val('');
                             document.getElementById("SendEmail_Message").innerHTML = "";
                            getInStockProductListByIds($("#selectedPOIds").val());

                        });

                            function getInStockProductListByIds(selectedPOsIds) {
                             var idListData = {
                                Ids:  selectedPOsIds
                             };
                             addAntiForgeryToken(idListData);

                             $.ajax({
                                cache: false,
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "@(Url.Action("getInStockProductListByIds", "InStockPendingShipments"))",
                                data: idListData,
                                 success: function (result) {
                                    if (result.Data != null || result.Data != '') {
                                          $('#selected-po-list').html('');
                                            $('#selected-po-list').delegate('li');
                                         $('#selected-po-list').append('<li class="list-header"><table><tr>' +
                                                    '<td style="width: 10%;font-weight: 600;"> SKU </td>' +
                                                    '<td tyle="font-weight: 600;">ProductNane</td>' +
                                                    '<td style="font-weight: 600;width: 20%;font-weight:600;text-align: right;position: relative;">Quantity</td>' +
                                                    '</tr></table ></li> ');
                                            for (var i = 0; i < result.Data.length; i++) {
                                                console.log('electedPOs', result.Data[i].SKU);
                                                $('#selected-po-list').append('<li><table><tr>' +
                                                    '<td style="width: 10%;"> <a target="_blank"  href="/admin/Product/Edit/' + result.Data[i].ProductId  + '">' + result.Data[i].SKU  + '</a></td>' +
                                                    '<td>' + result.Data[i].ProductNane + '</td>' +
                                                    '<td style="width: 20%;font-weight:600;text-align: right;position: relative;"> <div class="product-count">' + result.Data[i].Quantity + '</div></td>' +
                                                    '</tr></table ></li> ');
                                            }
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                    alert('Failed to find dispatch information.');
                                    return null;
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    </script>
                    <style>
                        .selected-po-list {
                            list-style: none;
                            padding-left: 0;
                            margin-top: 30px;
                            max-height: 280px;
                            overflow-y: auto;
                        }

                            .selected-po-list li {
                                height: 50px;
                                padding: 10px;
                                margin-bottom: 5px;
                                border: 1px solid #00c0ef47;
                            }

                                .selected-po-list li table {
                                    width: 100%;
                                }


                        .product-count {
                            position: absolute;
                            color: white;
                            height: 25px;
                            top: 0;
                            right: 10px;
                            text-align: center;
                            padding: 2px 0 0 0;
                            width: 25px;
                            border-radius: 50px;
                            background-color: #3c8dbc;
                        }

                        .list-header {
                            background-color: #7cc3ff30 !important;
                            height: 25px !important;
                            padding-top: 0 !important;
                            padding-bottom: 0 !important;
                        }
                    </style>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my action and it's working fine it returns string message

```
public virtual IActionResult SendInStockRequestEmail(string SelectedPOIds, string Message, string Subject)
{
    var inStockIds = new List<int>(Array.ConvertAll(SelectedPOIds.Split(','), Convert.ToInt32));
    string message = _inStockPendingShipmentService.SendInStockShipmentRequestEmail(inStockIds,  Message,  Subject);
    return Json(new DataSourceResult { Data = message });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default type of `<button>` is submit which submits the form data to the server . You can use input button instead :

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="send-email" value="Send Email" />
```